# wordpress 3.5 Text Editor with create new folders option

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering if, instead of having all the uploaded images going to the wp-content/uploads folder, there is a way I can upload images to different folders, for instance:

picture 1 to be uploaded to mydomain.com/images/nature/
picture 2 to be uploaded to mydomain.com/images/travel/

etc'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can this by using the ftp server place the images to different folder where you want to place your images. and after that link your images to different places in your website where you want.